# Parsing a webpage in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I need to create a web server that can parse a given webpage and index its content. I will use Boost to create the webserver. Is there support for parsing webpages in Boost or in C++ itself? If not, which other library can I use?

Comment: I don't think there is any unless you are brave enough to write your own parser using `spirit` (I am not sure if we can do at all with `spirit`)

Comment: And please do not resort to `std::regex` :) if at all it crossed your mind

Comment: Thanks @Arunmu. Any other library I can use?

Comment: Not C++, but a C library https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser